# google maps api coordinates from java to javascript

Tags: java, javascript, api, google-maps

If I want to share my geocoded spots in javascript and java how is this possible?

In Javascript the points are specified as

```
var point = GPoint(76.27562,9.97943);
```

In Java they are

```
GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(45005000, -93228900);
```

those seem to be two different formats, so how do I convert from one to the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`GeoPoint` requires lat/lng to be passed as integers, with degrees multiplied by `10^6`. So, you would need to multiply `76.27562` by `10^6` and convert that into an integer before passing it to the GeoPoint. The reverse process needs to be done for the reverse transformation.

Taken from [here](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/GeoPoint.html):

> GeoPoint(int latitudeE6, int longitudeE6) 
>             Constructs a GeoPoint with the given latitude and longitude, measured in microdegrees (degrees * 1E6).

*`1E6` is `10^6`*